# Why write more characters in C++11 auto return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I've recently seen lots of code snippets (on S.O.) declaring `int main()` as

```
auto main() -> int
{ 
 ... 
}
```

I see absolutely no reason to write it like this, since `int main()` is shorter (9 non white-space characters vs 15), concise, and perfectly valid code. Is there more than a "coolness/funkiness" factor involved in writing `auto main() -> int`?

Comment: Pretorian, clear enough, my conclusion is therefore "YES", should be avoided.

Comment: Alf is someone who consistently does this, and I've seen a comment from him saying he considers this the *One True Syntax* for functions in C++ because it's applicable to all use cases, while the traditional return type obviously isn't.

Comment: Praetorian, actually that's exactly the reason I've asked the question. I've seen it in his code snippets, and I respect what he's posting.

Comment: \when you have to write the actual type in anyway, auto seems redundant. I think auto is useful for situations where you don't *want* to have to type in the type or where you *cant* give the type. But it looks kewl(R). Anyway, I honestly wouldn't care either way if I encountered this in *real* code. I doubt that I would take the extra trouble to use it though.

Comment: @Galik, yeah, I'd use it whenever necessary, i.e. when the return type depends on the parameter via a `decltype`. However, I now understand why one might always use it, i.e. for consistency reasons.

Comment: @vsoftco Consistency is the best reason I have heard. I had not picked that point out of the comments before now. Perhaps some day all functions will be written this way. However, I think I might miss the easy to spot return type when its on the left rather than the right. My monitor is wider than it is tall and I *still* have to scroll in the IDE to find the end of some function declarations.